# How to automatically add type casts to printf style functions in c source code?

Tags: c, porting

I'm porting a large c project from Windows to Unix and the source contains many thousand calls for a logprint function which is declared like this:

```
VOID logprint(DWORD level, LPCSTR format, ...);
```

Now here are my two problems:

1.) Used format type specifiers are not portable

The code uses `%lu` for `ULONG` variables. On Windows this is fine because `ULONG` is a typedef for `unsigned long`. However when porting the code I cannot reproduce this typedef because `ULONG` must always be exactly 32-bit according to [[MS-DTYP]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc230390.aspx) (NB: With Microsoft's c compilers `unsigned long` is always 32-bit).
So I've created a windows types header file `wtypes.h` which defines the basic Windows data types with the help of `stdint.h` and `limits.h`.
Of course now this results in invalid reads because of the `%lu` specifier if the systems `unsigned long` is 64-bit and my `ULONG` is 32-bit. So I also have to add a `(unsigned long)` cast to all `ULONG` logprint arguments.
And `ULONG` is just one example of course ...

2.) Invalid format type specifiers used

In addition that code uses lots of invalid format specifiers. E.g. %d for DWORD arguments.

Of course it is easy to solve:

1. identify all logprint calls
2. identify the type of each argument
3. verify that the correct format specifier is used
4. add the correct type casts to the arguments

Example:

Replace:

```
ULONG ulMin, ulMax;
...
logprint(FATAL, "specified interval is invalid %ld..%u out of range",
                 ulMin, ulMax);
```

with:

```
logprint(FATAL, "specified interval is invalid %lu..%lu",
                 (unsigned long) ulMin, (unsigned long) ulMax);
```

But it would take me at least two weeks and my brain will be garbled after that.

So my actual question:

Are there any automated tools for making these kind of changes?

As a minimum requirement that tool would have to be able to identify the type of the arguments and prefix them with a type cast. Once the typecasts are there I can easily write a python script which fixes the format specifiers.

Comment: Adjustting the formats is preferred over casting, defintly! And as you are at it use the formatting macros from `inttypes.h`. The guy porting this to 64bit in 10 year or so will love you for this. ;-)

Comment: And regarding the work load: Map and reduce this with the help of your team mates.

Comment: This `logprint(FATAL, "specified interval is invalid %ld..%u out of range",
                 ulMin, ulMax);` should become `logprint(FATAL, "specified interval is invalid %"PRIu32"..%"PRIu32" out of range",
                 ulMin, ulMax);`.

Comment: @alk definitely agreed but there is no `inttypes.h` on Windows and the code should work everywhere. Of course I could add my own `inttypes.h` for Windows compilations. However, there are no other code slaves available for this task :( I'm wondering if this could be done with http://coccinelle.lip6.fr/ ...

Comment: I'm not suggesting `#if WINDOWS #define logprint(l,s,p...) ...`.

Comment: Creating `inttypes.h` for win is done within a wink, compared to the rest ... ;-)

Comment: If you have a code that must run on multiple platforms, then make it platform independent instead fixing here and then fixing there, this way work will never end. 1st make your platform abstraction layer, then change the code to use it.

Comment: You could define your own macros like the PRI macros from "inttypes.h", but tuned for the Windows types. E.g. `#define PRI_ULONG "lu"` for Windows, but `#define PRI_ULONG "u"` for Unix.

Comment: I hope the original code wasn't `logprint(FATAL, "specified interval is invalid %ld..%u out of range",
                 ulMin, ulMax);` because the format specifiers are horribly inconsistent.  The value parameters are both `ULONG`; the `%lu` and `%d` are inconsistent with each other (though `%lu` is probably correct).

Comment: Are you planning a 'one time port' from Windows to Unix and thereafter you will only maintain the Unix port, or are you looking to build on both Unix and Windows and bring enhancements from one to the other?  Will the ported source code ever be ported back to Windows?  Will changes in the Windows code ever need to be migrated to the Unix code?  You probably do things a bit differently depending on whether you need to maintain any degree of compatibility between the two code bases.

Comment: You could create your own header, `scnprtfmt.h` (scan, print format) which you include in your code.  The 'implementation' on systems with `inttypes.h` is primarily `#include <inttypes.h>`; on systems without native `inttypes.h`, you provide the equivalent functionality.  It is doable.  The main work is in changing format strings themselves to use the macros properly.

Answer (score 1):

Is the source of the `logprint` accessible? If it is, the best way seems to change it directly. It must contain type casting code for `va_arg` such as:

```
ul = va_arg(argp, ULONG);
```

then just change `ULONG` as you needed.

If it is not, just make your own wrapper function such as `logprint64` doing the similar task but casting the types for the arguments as needed. Substituting `logprint64` for `logprint` will take less than a hour, I guess.

Or, you may rewrite `logprint`. According to your post and reply, the `logprint` seems be in the following form:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

enum ErrCode { FATAL, MILD };
typedef unsigned short ULONG;

#define MAX 100
char Buf[MAX];

void logprint(enum ErrCode code, char *fmt, ...)
{
    va_list aptr;  
    va_start(aptr, fmt);
    vsprintf(Buf, fmt, aptr);
    va_end(aptr);
}

int main()
{
    ULONG ulMin = 97, ulMax = 99;

    logprint(FATAL,"interval is invalid %c..%c", ulMin, ulMax);
    printf("%s\n", Buf);

    return(0);
}
```

You can replace it with the following definition simulating `vsprintf`:

```
void logprint(enum ErrCode code, const char *fmt, ...)
{   // add your types as needed
    ULONG         h;
    unsigned long u;
    long          d;
    int           i;

    const char   *p;
    char       *buf;
    va_list    argp;
    va_start(argp, fmt);
    for (p = fmt, buf = Buf; *p != '\0'; p++) {
        if (*p != '%') {
            buf += sprintf(buf, "%c", *p); continue;
        }
        switch (*++p) { // change the type casting as needed
            case 'l':
                switch (*++p) {
                    case 'u':
                        u = (unsigned long) va_arg(argp, ULONG);
                        buf += sprintf(buf, "%lu", u); continue;
                    case 'd':
                        d = va_arg(argp, long);
                        buf += sprintf(buf, "%ld", d); continue;
                }
            case 'c':
                u = va_arg(argp, unsigned long);
                buf += sprintf(buf, "%lu", u); continue;
            case 'd':
                i = va_arg(argp, int);
                buf += sprintf(buf, "%d", i); continue;
        }
    }
    va_end(argp);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: No, the function uses `va_start`, `vsprintf`, `va_end`

Comment: @gollum I modified the posting to include a sample re-implementation of logprint assuming your logprint.